# How much thermal headroom?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, thermal, heat-protection

How much headroom is good design practice for a junction temperature calculation?

If a junction can be max. 150°C for example, what is the closest temperature one can be under and still feel "safe"?

Is it enough just to be under the maximum junction temperature in a worst case calculation or do you guys have a rule of thumb for how much under one should stay?
This is for a regulator without thermal shutdown.

I realise this is a "how long is a rope" kind of question, but I am uncertain on how reliable this formula is:

TJ = TA + ( R θJA × PD )

p.s.
datasheet
[datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf)

Comment: This would be junction temperature of which device? Does it have a part number or datasheet?

Comment: sorry. added datasheet now

Comment: How much life do you want it to have? every 15C above ambient halfs a components life.  personally... I use a 25C below max Tj as the ABSOLUTE maximum under worst-worst conditions (including thermal characteristics)

Comment: Our standard max operating temperature for silicon parts is 105 deg C.  That's a 45 deg C backoff (derating) from the accepted 150 deg C max temperature.  If for some reason that temperature is going to be exceeded, we do the analysis to show how much that reduces the life of the part.

Answer (score 0):

Reliability generally degrades the hotter you run a semiconductor. So you would want to aim for the lowest temperature. Other requirements might indirectly dictate acceptable device temperatures like UL. Like most engineering decisions, it is a compromise between conflicting requirements. If you find your junction temperature is too high, then look at options to mitigate this -
choose a different device

use multiple devices to spread the load

larger heatsink

reduce or stipulate an operational duty cycle

different circuit configuration (i.e. switching reg vs linear reg)

Selecting the best compromise relies on the skill and creativity of the engineer.

Comment: "use multiple devices to spread the load" is this possible? to use two regulators in parallell instead of one? or better asked: is it a good idea?

Comment: Probably not a good idea with the 34063. Using an external pass device might help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several considerations here:

- As for: what is the maximum temperature that it can go?  well, strictly speaking, you can go as close to the specified maximum as you want to. Considerations such as the comment by JonRB could be included, and you'll want to decide on X degrees below the specified limit. In all cases, you'll want to make sure that you do worst-case calculation with respect to *all* of the factors:  what is (with certainty) the maximum power dissipation under the device's actual operating conditions? what is the maximum ambient temperature? What is the actual/effective  from junction to ambient?
- The actual  from junction to ambient is affected by the PCB (assuming you don't use heatsinks) — wider traces reduce the effective , thicker copper, ground/power planes, etc. Typically, you get something between the two typically specified 's (junction to case, and junction to ambient). With an "infinite" heat sink, you'll get an effective  to ambient equal to the  junction to case.
- Consider also thermal cycles. For example, if you look into the IEC TR 62380, a standard that talks about reliability, you'll see formulas to compute things like failure rates of electronic components; operating temperature has a contribution to increase failure rates, but temperature swings have an even greater impact (say, if the device is powered on/off X number of times per day; or it may be operating outdoors, always on, but then it's subject to daytime-to-nighttime temperature variation, etc.).
- Lastly:  I notice that the datasheet includes suggested PCB designs by the manufacturer, and there seems to be an evaluation board; try to use those as guidelines (you don't need to do *exactly* as they do, but any designs recommended by the manufacturer have a good chance of being a good starting point).